# Python: skip lines while parsing html code and get rid of white spaces

Tags: python, html, string, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have the following `html` code:

```
html_doc = """
<h2> API guidance for developers</h2>
<h2>Images</h2>
<h2>Score descriptors</h2>
<h2>Downloadable XML data files (updated daily)</h2>
<h2>
                                    East Counties</h2>
<h2>
                                    East Midlands</h2>
<h2>
                                    London</h2>
<h2>
                                    North East</h2>
<h2>
                                    North West</h2>
<h2>
                                    South East</h2>
<h2>
                                    South West</h2>
<h2>
                                    West Midlands</h2>
<h2>
                                    Yorkshire and Humberside</h2>
<h2>
                                    Northern Ireland</h2>
<h2>
                                    Scotland</h2>
<h2>
                                    Wales</h2>
"""
```

How can I skip the first four lines and access the text strings such as `East Counties` and so forth?

My attempt does not skip the first four lines and returns the strings *including* the many white spaces embedded in the code (which I want to get rid of):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
for h2 in soup.find_all('h2'):
    next
    next
    next
    next
    print (str(h2.children.next()))
```

The desired result:

```
East Counties
East Midlands
London
North East
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why couldn't you just use `soup.find_all('h2')[4:]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `slicing` here, as `find_all` returns a list type so you can play around with it's index, like `[4:]` and to ignore white spaces use `strip()`

```
for h2 in soup.find_all('h2')[4:]:
    print(h2.text.strip())

East Counties
East Midlands
London
North East
North West
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for h2 in soup.find_all('h2')[4:]: # slicing to skip the first 4 elements
    print(h2.text.strip()) # get the inner text of the tag and then strip the white space
```